# mysql Query Timezone conversion

Tags: php, mysql, timezone, conventions, convert-tz

I have show times stored in all in Eastern and ID from timezone settings table. Timezone settings table has Timezone_id, GMT offset and the timezone Name.

GMT offset are stored like +6, -4, +3.5, -4.5, etc.

I am trying to write a query to pull the showtime converted to its original timezone. I am doing like this.

```
SELECT Date_format( CONVERT_TZ( CONVERT_TZ(A.START_TIME,  '+00:00',  '-5:00'),  
'+00:00',     CONCAT(B.GMT_OFFSET , ':00' )), '%Y-%m-%e %r:%i')  
AS  'start_time' from shows A, tz_settings B AND <<JOINS>>;
```

What I am doing here is first to convert the time from ET to GMT and then applying the GMT offset.

START_TIME is in date format like '2012-4-23 10:15:00'
Also, one more problem is converting formats like "3.5" to "3.30" to pass to Convert_TZ

EDIT: Table structure. Main fields.

```
   shows: 'id', 'show_name', 'stat_time', 'tz_id'
   tz_settings: 'tz_id', 'gmt_offset','tz_name'
```

Any ideas? Any other functions would help in the mix?

Comment: Can you post your table structure to better comprehend what you are doing ?

Comment: Just added the basic structure of two tables.

Comment: One thing that I can't understand, if you convert from ET to GMT, why do you want to exclude from that conversion the ones in ET ? since you state that all of then are in ET ? (or did I read your question wrong?)

Comment: You are right. I may have overstated that. Updated my question now.

Comment: well this has given me some sweat :) Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't really know what is the problem that you are having, but I just build 2 MYSQL tables with your structure:

**MySQL Tables**

```
TABLE shows ['id', 'show_name', 'start_time', 'tz_id']
TABLE tz_settings ['tz_id', 'gmt_offset','tz_name']
```

**And with this MySQL query:**

```
SELECT Date_format( CONVERT_TZ( CONVERT_TZ( A.START_TIME, '+00:00', '-5:00' ) , '+00:00', CONCAT( B.GMT_OFFSET, ':00' ) ) , '%Y-%m-%e %r:%i' ) AS 'start_time'
FROM shows A, tz_settings B
WHERE A.id =1
AND B.tz_id = A.tz_id
```

*The result was as expected!*

---

Regardless, You should be storing the GMT OFFSET with it's full format to simplify your query thus losing the CONCAT and improving performance.
Ex.: instead of +5, store +05:00

Does this helps you in any way ?

---

**EDITED TO INCLUDE MYSQL IF AND REPLACE**

```
SELECT Date_format( CONVERT_TZ( CONVERT_TZ( A.STAT_TIME, '+00:00', '-5:00' ) , '+00:00', if( B.GMT_OFFSET LIKE '%.5', REPLACE( B.GMT_OFFSET, '.5', ':30' ) , CONCAT( B.GMT_OFFSET, ':00' ) ) ) , '%Y-%m-%e %r:%i' ) AS 'start_time'
FROM shows A, tz_settings B
WHERE A.`id` =1
AND B.`tz_id` = A.`tz_id`
```

So, if the stored GMT OFFSET as .5 on it, it will be replaced by :30, otherwise, it will append the :00 to the existent value. (Tested and returns the value as expected)

Comment: Thats where the problem is. As you can see from my question, the GMT offset is stored as +3.5, +6, +4.5, etc. Fine with +6. But how do we deal with +4.5 (which should be +4:30)?

Comment: But you have no control for the GMT offset stored ? And what do you mean with: 4.5 should be 4:30 ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "But you have no control for the GMT offset stored ?". But I cannot change this format now. As for the 2nd question. Convert_TZ takes the 3rd argument in the form of "(+/-)00:00". So I cannot pass 4.5 here, while I can pass +6 as "+6:00".

Comment: Ok, so you cannot store the GMT OFFSET with a proper format, and you need to deal with stored values like "+4.5", using then as "+4:50"! Is that it? (please confirm, before I edit the answer)

Comment: Right. Except "as +4:50" should be " as +4:30". Thanks!

Comment: Check the query after the "EDITED". It now deals with the 30min issue.

Comment: Just starting thinking about he replace command and started working on that. Yours works just fine! Thanks much!